# VSCode inserts space after comment sequence

Tags: visual-studio-code, coding-style, comments

Whenever VSCode formats code, for almost all languages, it will insert spaces after the comment *escape sequence* (`//`, `#`, et cetera).

Although this does not work for C code, I assume that this *might* be some kind of global setting.
Is it possible to disable the insertion of this extra space somewhere? I follow a style where I don't use the extra spaces after "code-only" comments.

Any (lightweight) extensions that do this (or similar)? Should I make my own...?

I'd like for this solution to work for all languages, although Java is what I use the most.

I tried searching for some extensions related to comments, but it seems that there are none doing this. Is a linter what I need..?

*Sorry and thank you in advance!*

Answer (score 3):

There is a setting that should affect all languages:

```
Editor > Comments: Insert Space
```

It is enabled by default, uncheck it.

Comment: @Brahvim Does this answer not work for you?

Comment: The Java extensions don't let it work _for Java._ It seems to work for everything else!

Answer (score 1):

VS Code doesn't have a *default* formatter that works across every language so, there is no global solution for you. You will have to check, for every language you noticed such behavior, if the formatter is built in or not, and look for settings individually.

You commented about using Java, and VS Code Java support doesn't provides a formatter, so I suppose you have some Java extension installed, maybe from RedHat. If that's the case, I've noticed (based on extension's Readme) that It has a `Java: Open Java Formatter Settings` command, which says *opens the Eclipse formatter settings. Creates a new settings file if none exists.* It's been a long time I don't use Eclipse, so I'm not sure how its settings works, and if it does support the format rule you want. But I suggest you to take a look.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It seems that setting `java.format.comments.enabled` to `false` was somewhat helpful:
[`java.format.comments.enabled` setting in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJkcc.png)

However, it disables formatting for all comments, even JavaDoc ones.

Comment: This is not a global setting. Instead, comes from the Java extension (probably RedHat), and only works for Java relates files. If your question now is limited to Java files, and this setting does not fit your needs, I suggest you to open a feature request in extension’s repo (https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java) and update your question to be specific to Java.